# How can I skip over bad url's in my string when using request.get?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-requests

I have a string of url's that link to pdf's that I am trying to download. Some of the url's are no good, but my string is 41,000 long, so I'd like to use an exception of requests.get in order to pass over these url's and continue searching and download for the next on the list.

I've tried to use the except function like below, and I've tried it in a few other formats and locations as well, but I cannot seem to get it to perform.

```
try:
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    r.raise_for_status()
    with open(('file'+str(u)+'.pdf'),"wb") as code:
            code.write(r.content)
    print("pdf")
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    print(err)
    sys.exit(1)
```

i get this sort of readout when the error occurs:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host=
```

as well as

```
(Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname
```

Comment: If you want to know the bad URLs, you could just log the errors to a .txt file, and then wrap your `try` / `except` block in a while loop to continue parsing after an error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```py
# urls is the list of url
for url in urls:

    try:
        r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
        r.raise_for_status()
        with open(('file'+str(u)+'.pdf'),"wb") as code:
            code.write(r.content)
        print("pdf")

    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        print('[http_error]: {}'.format(err))

    except requests.exceptions.SSLError as bad_url:
        print('[bad_url]: {}'.format(bad_url))

    except Exception as e:
        print('[error]: {}'.format(e))
```